# Which process is eating my connection?

Tags: network, macos, resources

I found something is eating 100KB of my rx Internet connection.
 Doing iftop I found that most data is coming from 69.31.72.192.

Running this command line:

```
lsof -P -i -n | cut -f 1 -d " " | uniq
```

the list of processes is this

```
UserEvent
SystemUIS
Finder
sharingd
Dropbox
Google
```

Dropbox syncing is paused, Google goes away if I close Chrome, but the connection
is eaten anyway...

I came from linux and it is really shocking to see the system eating resources without knowing what is going on...

My four suspects are

```
UserEvent
SystemUIS
Finder
sharingd
```

I actually have two questions:

- How can I check which is the exact process that eats the connection?
- Can I take control on how the process(es) use my connection (which is really limited)?

Comment: turn off sharing. run netstat

Comment: How would you know which processes are taking resources  in Linux?

Comment: Linux - `ps aux` and netstat

Comment: Both those are on OSX so what is different?

Answer (score 1):

Activity Monitor has a network tab which should show you what you need. It has columns for process and sent/received packets & bytes.